# Avoiding a copy while searching in a std::map with composite keys

Tags: c++11, copy, stdmap

Suppose I have a map that maps two strings into a long:

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, long> sums = 
{
    {{"1", "2"}, 3},
    {{"3", "4"}, 7},
    {{"5", "6"}, 11},
};
```

If I want to search in a map, it takes a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. If I receive the two strings to search by via different ways, I have to construct `std::pair` on the fly, which AFAIK copies the strings:

```
std::string one = "1";
std::string two = "2";
std::pair<std::string, std::string> myPair = std::make_pair(one, two);
std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, long>::const_iterator it = sums.find(myPair);
```

If the map is searched A LOT, is there a way to not copy the strings to perform the search? There is no need to do a copy, it is required just by semantics of `std::map`.

EDIT: I am not attached to std::pair as key, it can be anything, even custom struct, as long as it is able to hold elements in the map by-value and search for them without a copy.

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? If you are using C++17, you can have std::string_view. Also `std::map::find` receives const reference so no copy operation is being performed.

Comment: c++11, but I am interested in a solution in higher versions, too.

Comment: I had a look on `std::string_view`, but I fail to see how it can help in this case. I cannot use `std::string_view` as key in the map, can I? And true, `std::map::find` does take a const reference, but to a `std::pair` I had to construct and this construction copied the strings.

Comment: I have written the answer and yes, you can use `std::string_view` as a key in a map.

Answer (score 1):

**C++17**

Since you said you are interested in a C++17 solution too, you can take advantage of `std::string_view` which does not allocate any memory but just holds the pointer to the actual data and the string length. Therefore, copy operation is lightweight.

The end solution would look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>, long> sums = {
        {{"1", "2"}, 3},
        {{"3", "4"}, 7},
        {{"5", "6"}, 11}
    };

    std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> myPair = std::make_pair("1", "2");
    auto it = sums.find(myPair);
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl; // output: 3

    return 0;
}
```

**C++11**

If you are limited to C++11, then you can use `char const*` as your `std::pair` members but then you need to define custom compare function like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>

struct cmp_str {
   bool operator()(std::pair<char const*, char const*> const& a,
                   std::pair<char const*, char const*> const& b) const {
      return std::strcmp(a.first, b.first) < 0;
   }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::pair<char const*, char const*>, long, cmp_str> sums = {
        {{"1", "2"}, 3},
        {{"3", "4"}, 7},
        {{"5", "6"}, 11}
    };

    std::pair<char const*, char const*> myPair = std::make_pair("1", "2");
    auto it = sums.find(myPair);
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please also expand the answer to an insertion on-the-fly, from two std::strings?

Comment: @JakubZaverka i have expanded my answer with the c++11 solution. How do you mean insertion on the fly?

Comment: If I later on want to insert more data into the map, e.g. dynamically loaded from DB as `std::string`s, how do I do that with std::string_view? Having a look in `std::string_view`, it is non-owning, so I would have to store the strings themselves in another place.

Comment: This would work `sums.insert({ { "2", "3" }, 4 });`

Comment: Yes, but "2" and "3" are static data in your example, what if I receive that dynamically in a function e.g. `insertInMap(std::string a, std::string b)`?

Comment: @JakubZaverka Then this would work `sums.insert({ { a.c_str(), b.c_str() }, 4 });`

Comment: The strings are passed by-value, meaning their lifecycle ends after the insert method ends, and `std::string_view` doesn't own the strings.

Comment: @JakubZaverka if you need to own the strings, then you shouldn't be using `std::string_view`

Answer (score 0):

**C++ 11**

Unfortunately you don't have `std::string_view` yet.

If you've received two `std::string` on the fly, you can always use `std::move` to avoid a copy if that's all that you want to do.

e.g. :

```
void findInMap(std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, long> map, 
   std::string && string1, std::string && string2)
{
   const auto key = std::make_pair(std::move(string1), std::move(string2));
   const auto itr = map.find(key);
   if(itr != map.end())
   {
      const auto value = itr->second;
   }
}
```

Comment: That destroys the strings I use to search by, so in order to search I need to do a copy, which kind of defeats the purpose. You are passing the strings by-value.

Comment: @JakubZaverka sure, you can change the `std::string` s to be passed by reference `std::string &&` and then the `std::move` would move the strings from wherever you owned them. The point is that to make a `std::pair` to search with you need to either copy the strings into it to avoid destroying the `std::string`s you want to search with or `std::move` them to avoid the copy but destroy the `std::string`s. Can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

## C++11 "Solution"

If you define a map such that the Key's const char* members point to strings that are safely stored in the value, you can probably do what you want. I've got the Value inside a `std::unique_ptr` to ensure that the const char* in the key always points to safe memory. It's possible that the `std::strings` in `Value` return the same value from `c_str` before and after moves, but I don't think the standard requires this.

```
struct Key
{
   const char* key1;
   const char* key2;
   bool operator<(const Key& k) {
     auto cmp1 = strcmp(key1, k.key1);
     if (cmp1 < 0) return true;
     if (cmp1 == 0) return strcmp(key2,k.key2) < 0;
     return false;
   }
};
struct Value
{
   const std::string key1;
   const std::string key2;
   long value;
};
 
std::map<Key, std::unique_ptr<Value>> map;
```

When inserting into such a monstrosity, you need to be careful though. Insert must be implemented using the map's value type - not (ever!) by using the `[]` operator. This is because the map's key cannot be changed, and using the `[]` operator default-creates the value. So after `[]` returns, it's too late to set the const char*'s in the key to what they need to be.

Instead you have to jump through these hoops.

```
std::pair<Key, std::unique_ptr<Value>> new_value;

new_value.second = std::make_unique<Value>(Value{"String1","String2"});
new_value.first = Key{new_value.second.key1.c_str(), new_value.second.key2.c_str()};

map.insert(std::move(new_value));
```

Lookups may then be performed without copying of strings

```
map.find(Key{"String1","String2"});
```

Whether or not this is worth it is left as an exercise for the reader.